# Family vs. class of distributions - definitions

Tags: classification, mathematical-statistics, terminology

What is the difference between a class of distributions and a family of distributions?

The class of (a,b,0) distributions is defined as:
[image]
The Binomial, Poisson, Geometric and Negative Binomial meet these criteria.

The exponential family is defined as

[image]

Is the classifier "class" reserved for those distributions that satisfy a recursive relationship and "family" reserved for those distributions that can be transformed into a specific functional form (i.e. not a recursive relationship)?

Comment: No, "class" is not restricted to recursively defined distributions.

Comment: Then what is the point of classifying distributions as part of a "class" and as part of a "family"? Don't class and family function as classification systems?

Answer (score 3):

Let us take a look at the use of the terms *class* and *family* in mathematics. See, e.g., [What is the difference between "family" and "set"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/what-is-the-difference-between-family-and-set) and [What are the differences between class, set, family, and collection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172966/difference-between-class-set-family-and-collection).

To summarize, a *class* of distributions would be any collection of distributions (i.e., *set*, if we forget advanced set-theoretical considerations motivated by Russell's paradox telling us that not every collection is a set). On the other hand, a *family* of distributions is an indexed collection of distributions.

The [Exponential family Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) states that "The term exponential class is sometimes used in place of 'exponential family'", which is consistent with the aforementioned definitions: any family of distributions is also a class of distributions if we don't emphasize the indexing.

Comment: +1 This 'index' is very loosely used, like in the exponential family it are the sufficient statistic $T(x)$, natural parameter $\eta(\theta)$, and base measure $h(x)$, that define a specific member in the set. Or in the Pearson distributions it are the values of parameters in a differential equation. Yet, in all these cases the family has every member defined. Sets of distributions that do not have this and would be called a class are for example the class of all discrete distributions, the class of all leptokurtic distributions, the class of all distributions with domain on $x \in [0,1]$ etc.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: So *the* exponential family is not a family of distributions, but a family of families of distributions (the family of Poisson distributions, the family of Gaussian distributions, &c.)?

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I agree now that 'the exponential family' is a family of families. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452280/is-there-just-one-exponential-family-or-are-there-many-exponential-families If it would be considered as a family of single densities/distributions, then it would encompass the entire space of potential distributions. For every potential distribution $f(x)$ there are some $h,T,\eta,\theta$ that match.