# How to prove that von Mises distribution belongs to exponential family?

Tags: probability, distributions, exponential-family, von-mises-distribution

Can anyone help me prove this, I'm not able to simplify the distribution to find the sufficient statistics, log normalizer, etc.

Comment: Could you write down the pdf in your post? [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math.

Comment: Apply the algorithm I give at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/519715/919.  It solves your problem immediately, with little work.

Answer (score 3):

**It is an exponential family distribution**

An exponential family distribution with parameter vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is one that has a log-density of the form:
$$
\log f(x \mid \boldsymbol{\theta})=\boldsymbol{\eta}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \cdot \mathbf{T}(x)+A(\boldsymbol{\theta})+B(x) .
$$
As can be seen, in an exponential family the log-density the argument variable $x$ must be separable from the parameter vector through a sufficient statistic $\mathbf{T}$. For the Von-Mises distribution we have the log-density:
\begin{align*}
\log \operatorname{Von-Mises}(x \mid \mu, \kappa)
&=\kappa \cos (x-\mu)-\log (2 \pi)-\log I_{0}(\kappa) \\
&= \kappa \cos(x)\cos(\mu) + \kappa \sin(x)\sin(\mu) -\log (2 \pi)-\log I_{0}(\kappa),
\end{align*}
where the support can be taken over any interval of length $2 \pi$. The term $\kappa \cos (x-\mu)$ can be manipulated into the form required for an exponential family, so it is an exponential family distribution with $T(x) = (\cos(x), \sin(x))$ and $\eta(\theta) = \kappa (\cos(\mu), \sin(\mu))$

Answer (score 0):

##### It is an exponential family distribution

An exponential family distribution with parameter vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is one that has a log-density of the form:

$$\log f(x|\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \boldsymbol{\eta}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \cdot \mathbf{T}(x) + A(\boldsymbol{\theta}) + B(x).$$

As can be seen, in an exponential family the log-density the argument variable $x$ must be separable from the parameter vector through a sufficient statistic $\mathbf{T}$.  For the Von-Mises distribution we have the log-density:

$$\begin{align}
\log \text{VonMises}(x|\mu, \kappa)
&= \kappa \cos(x-\mu) - \log(2 \pi) - \log I_0(\kappa) \\[6pt]
&= \kappa [\cos(x)\cos(\mu) + \sin(x)\sin(\mu)] - \log(2 \pi) - \log I_0(\kappa) \\[6pt]
&= \begin{bmatrix} \kappa \cos(\mu) \\ \kappa \sin(\mu) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \cos(x) \\ \sin(x) \end{bmatrix} - \log(2 \pi) - \log I_0(\kappa), \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

where the support can be taken over any interval of length $2 \pi$.  This is the form required for an exponential family, so it is an exponential family distribution.

---

**Update:** Hat-tip to [CechMS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/277071/) for correcting a major error in an earlier version of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternative paths to arrive at the solutions in the other answers. They are interesting to mention as they dive a bit deeper into the background.

#### von Mises-Fisher distribution

The von Mises distribution is a special case of the [von Mises-Fisher distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution). Using the expression for the latter shows quickly that it is an distribution in the exponential family.

$$f({\bf x}; \boldsymbol{\mu}, \kappa) = h(\kappa) e^{\kappa \boldsymbol{\mu}^T {\bf x} }$$

For the von Mises distribution you have a one-dimensional variable $\theta$ instead of the vector ${\bf x}$ and $$\boldsymbol{\mu} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\mu_\theta) \\ \sin(\mu_\theta) \end{bmatrix} \qquad \boldsymbol{x} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$$

#### Maximum entropy distribution

Note that the von Mises distribution is a maximum entropy distribution. A maximum entropy distribution [can be expressed as](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy#General_solution_for_the_maximum_entropy_distribution_with_linear_constraints) an exponential function $$p(x) \propto e^{\lambda_1f_1(x)+\lambda_2f_2(x)+ \dots + \lambda_n f_n(x)}$$ Here the functions $f_i(x)$ relate to functions whose expectation values are constrained (e.g. particular values for the moments).

The von Mises distribution is the case where the real and imaginary parts of the first [circular moments](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics#Moments) are constrained. That is we have constraints for:

$$E[\mathcal{Re}(e^{ix})] \qquad \text{and} \qquad E[\mathcal{Im}(e^{ix})]  $$

So the von Mises distribution can be described as

$$f(x) \propto e^{a  \mathcal{Re}( e^{ix}) + b  \mathcal{Im}( e^{ix} ) } =  e^{a \cos(x) + b \sin(x) } = e^{A \cos(x+\phi) } $$

where $A = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\phi = \text{atan}(b/a)$.